# quickblox auto relogin after disconnection

Tags: quickblox, reconnect

I would like to have my QBchat automatically be logged back in if it is disconnected. When I attempt to send a message and I am logged out, is their a callback function that I can implement to test if I am logged out? Also, if I am correct we must have a session establish with QB, than we log into our QBUUSER, than we must log into our QBChat to send messages?  How can reconnect all of these pieces if I lose connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of logout this method will be called

```
- (void)chatDidFailWithError:(int)code;
```

where code will be 0

Answer (score 0):

ChatDidFailWithError is a QBChat delegate method and checks for an active chat instance. If the chat has indeed failed auto-login with the user credentials saved in the DataManager singleton. (Example of which is in the QuickBlox framework's documentation)

- (void)chatDidFailWithError:(NSInteger)code {
      // recall user credentials from singleton class DataManager
      [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:[DataManager shared].currentUser];
  }

Comment: While this may be helpful a helpful answer (I personally don't know), it would be greatly enhanced with a bit of explanation.